# Testing as a logged in user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, authentication

I wanna test my functionals in my rails application, but the tests require a user/admin to be logged in. I have looked at many websites, but I cannot grasp what I really should be doing to make it work. I'm sure there there is an easy thing to do, but I cannot seem to find it.

I have seen the stubs command used, but I only get that it is an undefined method and I don't really know what it is supposed to do.

Any ideas on how I can run my tests as if it was an user/admin requesting them?

Thanks for any help I might get.

Comment: What authentication library are you using?

Comment: I am very new to rails and I believe I only use whatever came with the railsinstaller for windows. So I believe it is only got the already built in stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### acceptance/integration testing:

1. If you're using cucumber, just login as the user. Something like:

   fill_in 'users[username]', :with => "my username"
   fill_in 'users[password]', :with => "my password"
   click_button "Log In"
2. If you're using rspec+capybara, you can do something like this (assuming you're using Devise for authentication)

   ```
   # spec/spec_helper.rb
   include Warden::Test::Helpers

   # in spec/acceptance/some_spec.rb
   ...
   login_as FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   ```

### unit testing

- see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers if you're using Devise
- otherwise, you can implement similar functionality by writing to the `session` object, or by stubbing out `current_user` (assuming you call it that)

Comment: I'm not using anything. Just the basic tests, but I will try your last one and see if I can get it working.